# Error updating or deleted from database; "could not execute method"

Tags: android, database, sqlite

the Solution is at the bottom of my post.

First off, let me apologise for the length of this post but I've been pouring over the code for hours and I'm lost. I'm also pretty confused by the db aspects so my code duplicates some of the simplest tutorials I could find, even though I know aspects are deprecated or there are other methods which reduce the code length. I wasn't sure what was required or not, hence the large amount of code below.

The goal: I have a form that a user can fill in and save to a DB Table. I then display this data in another class to a ListView (this class also has additional functions above the listview). By clicking on one of the listview items, another form opens that looks identical to the original form, with all the info already populated from the database row. This form has a save and delete button which either lets you change some of the entry fields (EditText's and Spinner's) and save to update the row, or select delete. After updating or deleting, the activity finishes and takes you back to the listview class.

I won't bother adding the original form data as I know that is saving correctly. I also know that my data is transferring correctly into secondary form (the one I can modify/delete from), but I get the following in my logcat when trying to update or delete:

```
07-29 04:18:25.771: E/AndroidRuntime(2116): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-29 04:18:25.771: E/AndroidRuntime(2116): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
07-29 04:18:25.771: E/AndroidRuntime(2116):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3591)
07-29 04:18:25.771: E/AndroidRuntime(2116):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
07-29 04:18:25.771: E/AndroidRuntime(2116):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
07-29 04:18:25.771: E/AndroidRuntime(2116):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-29 04:18:25.771: E/AndroidRuntime(2116):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-29 04:18:25.771: E/AndroidRuntime(2116):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-29 04:18:25.771: E/AndroidRuntime(2116):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
07-29 04:18:25.771: E/AndroidRuntime(2116):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-29 04:18:25.771: E/AndroidRuntime(2116):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-29 04:18:25.771: E/AndroidRuntime(2116):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
07-29 04:18:25.771: E/AndroidRuntime(2116):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-29 04:18:25.771: E/AndroidRuntime(2116):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-29 04:18:25.771: E/AndroidRuntime(2116): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-29 04:18:25.771: E/AndroidRuntime(2116):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-29 04:18:25.771: E/AndroidRuntime(2116):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-29 04:18:25.771: E/AndroidRuntime(2116):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3586)
07-29 04:18:25.771: E/AndroidRuntime(2116):     ... 11 more
07-29 04:18:25.771: E/AndroidRuntime(2116): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-29 04:18:25.771: E/AndroidRuntime(2116):     at com.rone.glucometer.AddDBHelper.updateDetails(AddDBHelper.java:119)
07-29 04:18:25.771: E/AndroidRuntime(2116):     at com.rone.glucometer.UpdateDBDetails.clickUpdateDelete(UpdateDBDetails.java:420)
07-29 04:18:25.771: E/AndroidRuntime(2116):     ... 14 more
```

My AddDBHelper class looks like this:

```
public class AddDBHelper {

public static final String KEY_ROWID ="_id";
public static final String KEY_CATEG = "Category";
public static final String KEY_CATEGPOS = "Category_Pos";
public static final String KEY_BGL = "BGL";
public static final String KEY_CARBS = "Carbs";
public static final String DB_NAME = "Glucometer.db";
public static final String DB_TABLE = "Journal";
private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

private DbHelper myDBHelper;
private final Context mContext;
private SQLiteDatabase glucoDB;

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DB_TABLE + " (" +
            KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            KEY_CATEG + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            KEY_CATEGPOS + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            KEY_BGL + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            KEY_CARBS + " TEXT NOT NULL);"

);}
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DB_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

}


public AddDBHelper(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public AddDBHelper open() throws SQLException {
    myDBHelper = new DbHelper(mContext);
    glucoDB = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    myDBHelper.close();
}

public long createEntry(String Category, String CategoryPos, String BGL, String Carbs) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_CATEG, Category);
    cv.put(KEY_CATEGPOS, CategoryPos);
    cv.put(KEY_BGL, BGL);
    cv.put(KEY_CARBS, Carbs);
return glucoDB.insert(DB_TABLE, null, cv); }

public Cursor getEntries() {        
    return glucoDB.query(DB_TABLE, new String[] {
            KEY_ROWID,
            KEY_CATEG,
            KEY_CATEGPOS,
            KEY_BGL,
            KEY_CARBS}, null, null, null, null, null); }

public void updateDetails(DBDetails dbdetails) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(AddDBHelper.KEY_ROWID, UpdateDBDetails.newRow);
    cv.put(AddDBHelper.KEY_CATEG, UpdateDBDetails.newCateg);
    cv.put(AddDBHelper.KEY_CATEGPOS, UpdateDBDetails.newCategPos);
    cv.put(AddDBHelper.KEY_BGL, UpdateDBDetails.newBGL);
    cv.put(AddDBHelper.KEY_CARBS, UpdateDBDetails.newCarbs);

    db.update(DB_TABLE, cv, KEY_ROWID + "=?", new String[] {String.valueOf(UpdateDBDetails.newRow)});
}


public void deleteDetails(DBDetails dbdetails) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(DB_TABLE, KEY_ROWID +"=?", 
            new String[] {String.valueOf(UpdateDBDetails.newRow)});
    db.close();
}}
```

My ListView Activity is as follows:

```
public class FuncLogbook extends DashMenuActivity implements OnItemClickListener {

private ListView list_LogbookResults;
private ListAdapter list_LogbookAdap;
private ArrayList<DBDetails> LogbookArrayList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView (R.layout.dash_logbook);

    list_LogbookResults = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_logbookResults);
    list_LogbookResults.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    LogbookArrayList = new ArrayList<DBDetails>();
    list_LogbookAdap = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, populateList());
    list_LogbookResults.setAdapter(list_LogbookAdap); }

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public List<String> populateList() {
    List<String> BGLResultsList = new ArrayList<String>();

    AddDBHelper logbook = new AddDBHelper(this);
    logbook.open();
    Cursor cur = logbook.getEntries();
    startManagingCursor(cur);

    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
        String RowID = cur.getString(0);
        String Category = cur.getString(1);
        String CategoryPos = cur.getString(2);
        String BGL = cur.getString(3);
        String Carbs = cur.getString(4);


        DBDetails detailsClass = new DBDetails();
        detailsClass.setuCateg(Category);
        detailsClass.setuCategPos(CategoryPos);
        detailsClass.setuBGL(BGL);
        detailsClass.setuCarbs(Carbs);


        LogbookArrayList.add(detailsClass);
        BGLResultsList.add("BGL: " + BGL + "\nRow ID: " + RowID);
    }

    return BGLResultsList;
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    LogbookArrayList = new ArrayList<DBDetails>();
    list_LogbookAdap = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, populateList());
    list_LogbookResults.setAdapter(list_LogbookAdap);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    LogbookArrayList = new ArrayList<DBDetails>();
    list_LogbookAdap = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, populateList());
    list_LogbookResults.setAdapter(list_LogbookAdap);
}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {      
    Intent UpdateDBDetails = new Intent(this, UpdateDBDetails.class);

    DBDetails clickedObject = LogbookArrayList.get(arg2);
    Bundle dataBundle =  new Bundle();
    dataBundle.putString("clickeduCateg", clickedObject.getuCateg());
    dataBundle.putString("clickeduCategPos", clickedObject.getuCategPos());
    dataBundle.putString("clickeduBGL", clickedObject.getuBGL());
    dataBundle.putString("clickeduCarbs", clickedObject.getuCarbs());


    UpdateDBDetails.putExtras(dataBundle);
    startActivity(UpdateDBDetails);
}}
```

The data is gathered to my DBDetails class:

```
public class DBDetails {

private String uCateg;
private String uCategPos;
private String uBGL;
private String uCarbs;

public String getuCateg() {
    return uCateg;
}

public void setuCateg(String uCateg) {
    this.uCateg = uCateg;
}

public String getuCategPos() {
    return uCategPos;
}

public void setuCategPos(String uCategPos) {
    this.uCategPos = uCategPos;
}

public String getuBGL() {
    return uBGL;
}

public void setuBGL(String uBGL) {
    this.uBGL = uBGL;
}

public String getuCarbs() {
    return uCarbs;
}

public void setuCarbs(String uCarbs) {
    this.uCarbs = uCarbs;
}
```

And finally, my form that displays the data:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.updatedbdetails);

update_category_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.update_category_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> category_adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.category_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    category_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    update_category_spinner.setAdapter(category_adapter);

    update_category_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            newCat = update_category_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            newCatPos = (update_category_spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() + " Position");
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        }
    });

Bundle takeBundledData = getIntent().getExtras();

    bundleduRowId = takeBundledData.getString("clickeduRowId");
    bundleduCateg = takeBundledData.getString("clickeduCateg");
    bundleduCategPos = takeBundledData.getString("clickeduCategPos");
    bundleduBGL = takeBundledData.getString("clickeduBGL");
    bundleduCarbs = takeBundledData.getString("clickeduCarbs");

CategoryPosition = String.valueOf(bundleduCategPos.charAt(0));
    update_category_spinner.setSelection(Integer.parseInt(CategoryPosition), true);
update_edit_bgl.setText(bundleduBGL);
    update_edit_carbs.setText(bundleduCarbs); }

public static double round(double unrounded, int precision, int roundingMode) {
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(unrounded);
    BigDecimal rounded = bd.setScale(precision, roundingMode);
    return rounded.doubleValue();
}


public void checkNewBGL() {
    String checkBGL = update_edit_bgl.getText().toString();
    if (checkBGL.matches("")) {
        NewBGLValid = "";
    } else {
        float BGLUnRound = Float.parseFloat(update_edit_bgl.getText().toString());
         double BGLRound= round(BGLUnRound, 1, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
         NewBGLValid = String.valueOf(BGLRound);
    }
    return;
    }

    public void checkNewCarbs() {
    String checkCarbs = update_edit_carbs.getText().toString();
    if (checkCarbs.matches("")) {
        NewCarbsValid = "0";
    } else {        
        NewCarbsValid = update_edit_carbs.getText().toString();
    }
    return;
    }

public void clickUpdateDelete(View v) {

    checkNewBGL();
    checkNewCarbs();

    newCateg = newCat;
    newCategPos = newCatPos;
    newBGL = NewBGLValid;
    newCarbs = NewCarbsValid;

DBDetails dbdetails = new DBDetails();

    dbdetails.setuCateg(newCateg);
    dbdetails.setuCategPos(newCategPos);
    dbdetails.setuBGL(newBGL);
    dbdetails.setuCarbs(newCarbs);

if (v.getId() == R.id.update_button_delete) {
        AddDBHelper deleteEntry = new AddDBHelper(this);
        deleteEntry.deleteDetails(dbdetails);
    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.update_button_save) {
        AddDBHelper updateEntry = new AddDBHelper(this);
        updateEntry.updateDetails(dbdetails);
    }   
}}
```

I updated to

```
public void updateDetails(DBDetails dbdetails) { 
SQLiteDatabase db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put(AddDBHelper.KEY_CATEG, UpdateDBDetails.newCateg); 
cv.put(AddDBHelper.KEY_CATEGPOS, UpdateDBDetails.newCategPos); 
cv.put(AddDBHelper.KEY_BGL, UpdateDBDetails.newBGL);
cv.put(AddDBHelper.KEY_CARBS, UpdateDBDetails.newCarbs);
db.update(DB_TABLE, cv, KEY_ROWID + "=?", new String[] {UpdateDBDetails.getRowId});}
```

and added to the UpdateDBDetails:

```
getRowId = dbdetails.getuRow();
```

though same issue is occurring. Also, at this stage, I'm not closing my cursor cause if I hit the 'back' button instead of save or delete, it crashes due to trying to query an already closed cursor; I suppose I'll tackle that issue later. You are right, I did forget to define UpdateDBDetails, but I have passed in the DBDetails context to the method, so I've now changed to

```
public void updateDetails(DBDetails dbdetails) {
SQLiteDatabase db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase(); 
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues(); 
cv.put(AddDBHelper.KEY_CATEG, dbdetails.getuCateg()); 
cv.put(AddDBHelper.KEY_CATEGPOS, dbdetails.getuCategPos()); 
cv.put(AddDBHelper.KEY_BGL, dbdetails.getuBGL()); 
cv.put(AddDBHelper.KEY_CARBS, dbdetails.getuCarbs()); 
db.update(DB_TABLE, cv, KEY_ROWID + "=?", new String[] {dbdetails.getuRow()}); }
```

but again, same issues.

**Solution:**

My DBDetails.java has the following lines added:

```
 public String getuRow() {
    return uRow;
}

public void setuRow(String uRow) {
    this.uRow = uRow;
}
```

My Listview (FuncLogbook.Java) had the following lines added\changed:

```
public List<String> populateList() {
    List<String> BGLResultsList = new ArrayList<String>();

    AddDBHelper logbook = new AddDBHelper(this);
    logbook.open();
    Cursor cur = logbook.getEntries();
    startManagingCursor(cur);

    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
        String RowID = cur.getString(0);
        String Category = cur.getString(3);
        String CategoryPos = cur.getString(4);
        String BGL = cur.getString(5);
        String Carbs = cur.getString(6);

DBDetails detailsClass = new DBDetails();
        detailsClass.setuRow(RowID);
        detailsClass.setuCateg(Category);
        detailsClass.setuCategPos(CategoryPos);
        detailsClass.setuBGL(BGL);
        detailsClass.setuCarbs(Carbs);
LogbookArrayList.add(detailsClass);
}
return BGLResultsList; }

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {      
    Intent UpdateDBDetails = new Intent(this, UpdateDBDetails.class);

    DBDetails clickedObject = LogbookArrayList.get(arg2);
    Bundle dataBundle =  new Bundle();
    dataBundle.putString("clickeduRowId", clickedObject.getuRow());
    dataBundle.putString("clickeduCateg", clickedObject.getuCateg());
    dataBundle.putString("clickeduCategPos", clickedObject.getuCategPos());
    dataBundle.putString("clickeduBGL", clickedObject.getuBGL());
    dataBundle.putString("clickeduCarbs", clickedObject.getuCarbs());
        UpdateDBDetails.putExtras(dataBundle);
    startActivity(UpdateDBDetails);
}
```

MY DB helper class (AddDBHelper.java) shows the following:

```
public void updateDetails(DBDetails dbdetails) {

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(AddDBHelper.KEY_CATEG, dbdetails.getuCateg());
    cv.put(AddDBHelper.KEY_CATEGPOS, dbdetails.getuCategPos());
    cv.put(AddDBHelper.KEY_BGL, dbdetails.getuBGL());
    cv.put(AddDBHelper.KEY_CARBS, dbdetails.getuCarbs());
int count = glucoDB.update(DB_TABLE, cv, KEY_ROWID + "=?", new String[] {String.valueOf(dbdetails.getuRow())});
    Log.v("AddDbHelper", "Row " + dbdetails.getuRow() + " updated? " + count);
}

public void deleteDetails(DBDetails dbdetails) {

    int count = glucoDB.delete(DB_TABLE, KEY_ROWID +"=?", 
            new String[] {String.valueOf(dbdetails.getuRow())});
    Log.v("AddDbHelper", "Row " + dbdetails.getuRow() + " deleted? " + count);
}
```

And finally, my UpdateDBDetails.java (which contains the form with info to be modified or deleted) shows:

```
onCreate...{
Bundle takeBundledData = getIntent().getExtras();

    bundleduRowId = takeBundledData.getString("clickeduRowId");
    bundleduCateg = takeBundledData.getString("clickeduCateg");
    bundleduCategPos = takeBundledData.getString("clickeduCategPos");
    bundleduBGL = takeBundledData.getString("clickeduBGL");
    bundleduCarbs = takeBundledData.getString("clickeduCarbs");
}

public void clickUpdateDelete(View v) {


    checkNewBGL();
    checkNewCarbs();

    newCateg = newCat;
    newCategPos = newCatPos;
    newBGL = NewBGLValid;
    newCarbs = NewCarbsValid;

AddDBHelper modifyEntry = new AddDBHelper(this);
    modifyEntry.open();

    DBDetails dbdetails = new DBDetails();

    dbdetails.setuRow(bundleduRowId);

    if (v.getId() == R.id.update_button_delete) {
        modifyEntry.deleteDetails(dbdetails);
    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.update_button_save) {
        dbdetails.setuCateg(newCateg);
        dbdetails.setuCategPos(newCategPos);
        dbdetails.setuBGL(newBGL);
        dbdetails.setuCarbs(newCarbs);
modifyEntry.updateDetails(dbdetails);
    }   
    modifyEntry.close();
    finish();
}
```

Comment: Please post the full logcat trace, the information in there is invaluable.

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
... at com.rone.glucometer.AddDBHelper.updateDetails(AddDBHelper.java:119)` What is line 119 in AddDBHelper (it's in updateDetails())? I'm guessing the is the first time you reference `UpdateDBDetails`...

Comment: **Line 118:** `public void updateDetails(DBDetails dbdetails) {`
**Line 119:** `SQLiteDatabase db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();`

Comment: Oh, whenever you create a new AddDBHelper you need to open it first, I just updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where you define `UpdateDBDetails`. But I have a few suggestions regarding SQLiteDatabase.update().

**First** add the row ID to your UpdateDBDetails object and provide a get method.

**Then** use the update method like this:

```
public void updateDetails() {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(AddDBHelper.KEY_CATEG, UpdateDBDetails.newCateg);
    cv.put(AddDBHelper.KEY_CATEGPOS, UpdateDBDetails.newCategPos);
    cv.put(AddDBHelper.KEY_BGL, UpdateDBDetails.newBGL);
    cv.put(AddDBHelper.KEY_CARBS, UpdateDBDetails.newCarbs);

    db.update(DB_TABLE, cv, KEY_ROWID + "=?", new String[] {UpdateDBDetails.getuRow()});
}
```

When you update a row its ID should not change, otherwise you would be creating a new row or updating a different row... So the ContentValues object shouldn't attempt to add anything concerning `AddDBHelper.KEY_ROWID` but your SQLiteDatabase.update()'s WHERE clause should have the current row's ID. Hope that makes sense.

**Also** whenever you use `new AddDBHelper` or `myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase()` (or if you ever use a Cursor directly), you should close these objects when you are done. Otherwise the are kept around, consuming memory unnecessarily.

**Addition from LogCat**

I see your LogCat and I'm guessing that there is something wrong with `UpdateDBDetails` however I just noticed where you call updateDetails() and recommend:

Adding the row ID to DBDetails so you can do this:

```
AddDBHelper helper = new AddDBHelper(this);
helper.open();

DBDetails dbdetails = new DBDetails();
dbdetails.setuRow(bundleduRowId);

if (v.getId() == R.id.update_button_delete) {
    helper.deleteDetails(dbdetails);
} else if (v.getId() == R.id.update_button_save) {
    dbdetails.setuCateg(newCateg);
    dbdetails.setuCategPos(newCategPos);
    dbdetails.setuBGL(newBGL);
    dbdetails.setuCarbs(newCarbs);
    helper.updateDetails(dbdetails);
}   

helper.close();
```

And last AddDbHepler:

```
public void updateDetails(DBDetails dbdetails) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(AddDBHelper.KEY_CATEG, dbdetails.newCateg);
    cv.put(AddDBHelper.KEY_CATEGPOS, dbdetails.newCategPos);
    cv.put(AddDBHelper.KEY_BGL, dbdetails.newBGL);
    cv.put(AddDBHelper.KEY_CARBS, dbdetails.newCarbs);

    glucoDB.update(DB_TABLE, cv, KEY_ROWID + "=?", new String[] {String.valueOf(dbdetails.getuRow())});
}
```

**Logcat**

Both update and delete return a Integer of how many rows were affected, you can see them yourself like this:

```
int count = glucoDB.update(DB_TABLE, cv, KEY_ROWID + "=?", new String[] {String.valueOf(dbdetails.getuRow())});
Log.v("AddDbHelper", "Row " + dbdetails.getuRow() + " updated? " + count);
```

If you see "...updated? 1" then it worked, otherwise the ID stored in DBDetails is off.

Comment: Yea, comments have very limited formatting, but they can be edited (for 5 minutes) and deleted. It's easiest to edit blocks of code into your question.

Comment: Removed the jumble of comments and shifted them to the bottom of my original post. Hope that makes it easier to read.

Comment: Ok, I see the logic here and it makes sense. Unfortunately since making those changes, the buttons now don't do anything when clicked - no logcat entries, no errors, nothing...it's as if it's not detecting the click.

Comment: I don't see the logcat statements myself, are they in the update functions? Or are you talking about no more error statements... which means the code runs fine? To see the updates immediately you will need to call notifyDataSetChanged() on your adapter.

Comment: Yes sorry, I meant no error messages.
I added a `finish();` statement below and that seems to get picked up when I press either button, but I don't think the data is actually being modified, I can add new rows, close the app, go back in and the new rows will show up (in fact, they will show immediately after adding them), but the listview still shows old values, indicating the updates didn't work...it will also show rows which were supposed to have been deleted, indicating that didn't work either.

Comment: Ok, you can check out the actual SQL statements in your debugger to see if they make sense. You can also use logcat statements like I added to my answer. I have a feeling the ID being passed in update() and delete() doesn't point to the right place.

Comment: Something has definitely fallen over because logcat says "Row null updated? 0"

Comment: Thanks Sam..all resolved and resolution is attached below my original post. The reason I was getting `Row null` was due to typing errors where I had written "uRow" half the time and "uRowId" the other half. Once I spotted that, your solutions worked perfectly. Thank You.